# MySQL: SELECT DISTINCT multiple columns, with the first result on some columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have columns `a, b` in a table in a MySQL database. What I'm trying to do is to select the distinct values of `a` with an arbitrary value of `b` - let's say the first one, but I actually don't care which one.

Something like the query below will give me all *distinct* values on both columns, so it is not good for me (too many results in my case).

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b
FROM my_table;
```

Any suggestions?
In case I want 2 values of `b` for each `a` value, how is that possible?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired result ?

Comment: Try this: `SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY a,b;`

Comment: What about the case where there be only one distinct value for `a`?  You should show us sample input and output; a picture is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **[`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html)** feature, like:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM my_table
GROUP BY a;
```

See my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c00e7/2).

---

### UPDATE

No `DISTINCT` is needed at all.
Thanks to [dnoeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2527905/dnoeth) for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess from what I think your'e trying to do:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a as distinct, 
        ( SELECT b FROM my_table WHERE c = a LIMIT 1 ) as arbitary 
        FROM my_table;
```